# Why is Edge body scrollbar different from Firefox body scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, firefox, microsoft-edge

I'm creating a chatting list, it works fine on Firefox, but it's not on Microsoft Edge.

CSS of the root `<div class="chatting">`:

```
.chatting {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    width: 206px
}
```

Result on **Firefox:**

[image]

and on **Microsoft Edge:**

[image]

The second snapshot means: `right: 5px;` is not enough. Why? That's my problem or Edge problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Edge (and newer Internet Explorers) use an autohiding scrollbar, which doesn't occupy layout space. Adding `-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar` to your CSS makes the scrollbar behave like the scrollbar in Firefox (and Chrome and other browsers), which should fix the issue.

> **scrollbar**
>
> Indicates the element displays a classic scrollbar-type control when its content overflows.
> Unlike -ms-autohiding-scrollbar, scrollbars on elements with the -ms-overflow-style property set to scrollbar always appear on the screen and do not fade out when the element is inactive.
> Scrollbars do not overlay content, and therefore take up extra layout space along the edges of the element where they appear.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441298.aspx

Comment: I've added `-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar` to `<body>`. It's working. Many thanks :)