# Body scrollbar stopped autohiding

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I was working on a page with an overflow: auto DIV.
It showed a fancy narrow autohiding scrollbar.

At some point that fancy scrollbar turned into the normal clunky one.
I tried to backtrace but can't seem to get it restored.

You can see on the screenshot that the two scrollbars look different. Mine wasn't red though but subtle blueish.

[image]

Image borrowed from: [Why is Edge body scrollbar different from Firefox body scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773216/why-is-edge-body-scrollbar-different-from-firefox-body-scrollbar)

Comment: You did not get answer from there?

Comment: No, his question is about the (mis)positioning. Mine is about how tho get the auto-hiding version over the normal look.